# found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I get this error when running a new React native project with version 0.64.2.

Our React Native project has the RN version 0.64.2. It worked fine on my M1 Macbook. Recently I upgraded to an M2 Pro Macbook. When I tried running the project in it, I got the below-mentioned error.

To isolate the error, I created a new React Native project and got the same error in that as well.

```
nesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a[6](AsyncSignalHandler.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: warning: ignoring file '/Users/praveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-gdbuhokxonzeopegdeygrvchwxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a[5](AsyncServerSocket.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: warning: ignoring file '/Users/praveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-gdbuhokxonzeopegdeygrvchwxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a[4](AsyncPipe.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: warning: ignoring file '/Users/praveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-gdbuhokxonzeopegdeygrvchwxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a[3](AsymmetricMemoryBarrier.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: warning: ignoring file '/Users/praveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-gdbuhokxonzeopegdeygrvchwxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a[2](Assume.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FKUserDefaultsPlugin, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperClient, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitLayoutPlugin, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitNetworkPlugin, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitReactPlugin, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBridge, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKDescriptorMapper, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKIOSNetworkAdapter, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### Steps to reproduce

```
React Native version : 0.64.2
Node version : v14.20.0
Xcode version : 14.1 (14B47b)
```

Created a new project with the command

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.64.2`

Run the project in ios

`npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14'`